# REST API v2 vs. v3

Tags: rest, wordpress-rest-api

I want to develop a new application which uses REST API. There are versions v1, v2 and v3.

What are the main differences between v1, v2 and v3?

My application will interact with WordPress.
Should I go for v3 at all costs?

Comment: The versions are most likely specific to the application. Developers would rather release an API with a new version than change an existing API that is currently in use by their clients. Newer could mean more stable with new features and/or undiscovered bugs :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a singular "REST API". Rather, REST is a style of making APIs that is widely used. One component of this style is the version. It appears you are looking at creating an application to interface with a [Wordpress API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

In general, it is always best to use the latest supported version of any API or library. However, I cannot seem to find any evidence of a WordPress version 3 API - only [version 2](http://v2.wp-api.org/).

Comment: Not quite. The v[123] are *your* application version numbering. See the quote in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer in Wordpress REST API doc:

> Namespaces in general should follow the pattern of vendor/v1, where vendor is typically your plugin or theme slug, and v1 represents the first version of the API. If you ever need to break compatibility with new endpoints, you can then bump this to v2

[See for more](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)